# Vimperator could not be installed because it is not compatible with Iceweasel 17.0.9

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, vimperator, iceweasel

I use Iceweasel 17.0.9 on Debian Testing (Jessie).

When I visit https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimperator/contribute/roadblock/?src=dp-btn-primary&version=3.8 and try to install Vimperator 3.8, I get this error:

> Vimperator could not be installed because it is not compatible with
>   Iceweasel 17.0.9

How can I install Vimperator on Iceweasel 17.0.9?

Comment: I noted there is the word Testing in the title I'm not familiar with the software package so not 100% sure if it's applicable but just wanted to remind you "Questions about bugs in pre-release/beta software or prototype hardware are off-topic"

Comment: @50-3 Thanks. This question is not about a bug. It's a question about why a stable version of Vimperator doesn't install on a stable version of Iceweasel or Firefox, although the operating system I am using is not stable yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Quick solution

Install Vimperator 3.7.1 instead of Vimperator 3.8. Go to https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimperator/contribute/roadblock/?src=version-history&version=3.7.1 and click 'Add to Firefox' button.

#### Long solution

This is same as the previous solution. The steps below document how you can reach the URL mentioned in the previous solution from the Vimperator addon page in a step by step manner.

1. Go to https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimperator/
2. Scroll down to 'Version information' section. Click on this section.
3. At the bottom of this section, click on 'See complete version history' link. You'll land on https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimperator/versions/.
4. Scroll down to 'Version 3.7.1' section and click on 'Continue to download'. You'll land on https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimperator/contribute/roadblock/?src=version-history&version=3.7.1.
5. Click 'Add to Firefox' button.

#### Why does Version 3.7.1 work but Version 3.8 doesn't?

Visit https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimperator/versions/. Scroll down to Version 3.8, then click "View source" link below it. The [install.rdf file of Vimperator 3.8](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/files/browse/230597/) shows that Vimperator 3.8 can be installed on Iceweasel/Firefox versions 20.0-26.0.

```
<em:targetApplication>
    <Description>
        <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
        <em:minVersion>20.0</em:minVersion>
        <em:maxVersion>26.0</em:maxVersion>
    </Description>
</em:targetApplication>
```

Now visit https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimperator/versions/ and scroll down to Version 3.7.1, then click "View source" link below it. The [install.rdf file of Vimperator 3.7.1](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/files/browse/209512/) shows that it can be installed on Iceweasel/Firefox versions 17.0-23.0.

```
<em:targetApplication>
    <Description>
        <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
        <em:minVersion>17.0</em:minVersion>
        <em:maxVersion>23.0</em:maxVersion>
    </Description>
</em:targetApplication>
```

Therefore, install Vimperator 3.7.1 from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimperator/contribute/roadblock/?src=version-history&version=3.7.1.